# Maximize over vector with conditional expression

Tags: mathematical-optimization, vector

I am unable to maximize a function containing an `If` statement and a vector variable. To give an MWE (not my original problem), consider the following:

```
x = {x1, x2};
Maximize[If[x[[2]] == 1, 1, -x[[1]]^2], x]
```

This returns no error, but returns

```
Maximize[If[x2 == 1, 1, -x[[1]]^2], {x1, x2}]
```

As you can see, it refuses to convert the second vector element to `x1`. If I do that manually by entering

```
x = {x1, x2};
Maximize[If[x[[2]] == 1, 1, -x1^2], x]
```

then it easily spits out

```
{1, {x1 -> 33/10, x2 -> 1}}
```

Can anybody offer me some insight into what's going on here? Is there a way to tweak it that doesn't involve manual rewriting? (If I have to type out all vector operations, it's going to be a long ugly formula...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `Piecewise[]` to represent your function, `Indexed[]` to extract coordinates, and `FullRegion[2]` as the search domain. Thus:

```
Maximize[Piecewise[{{1, Indexed[x, 2] == 1}}, -Indexed[x, 1]^2], x ∈ FullRegion[2]]
   {1, {x -> {33/10, 1}}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't pretend I know what's going on here, but this solves my current problem, and now I can look more into these functions to learn more. :)

Comment: "...now I can look more into these functions to learn more." - yes, that was the intention. :)

Comment: (I'm just waiting for the site to allow me to accept your answer.. one more minute :))